# Polynomials in one variable with infinitely many roots.

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Can a non-zero polynomial in one variable have infinitely many roots ?
>
> Can a non-zero polynomial in one variable have uncountably many roots ?

**Motivation**: over $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$, $X^2-4$ has 4 roots.

When it comes to polynomials with coefficients over an integral domain, the answer is clearly negative (in that case, a polynomial can't have more roots than its degree).

What happens with a ring that has zero divisors ?

Comment: What about the zero polynomial? In $\mathbb R$ it has as many roots as $\mathbb R$ is big.

Comment: @user2345215 off course, but it's not very interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R = \prod_{i \in I} (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ with elementwise addition and multiplication. Then $t \mapsto (2,2,...)t$ is a non-zero polynomial over $R$ with $2^{|I|}$ many zeros.

Comment: this also covers the case of *uncountably* many zeros

Answer (score 6):

Here's a very simple construction: let $R$ be the ring

$$ \mathbf{Z}[x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots] / \langle x_0^2 + 1, x_1^2 + 1, x_2^2 + 1, \ldots \rangle $$

Then every $x_i$ is a root of the polynomial $t^2 + 1$ over $R$.

---

A more trimmed down example is the ring

$$ \mathbf{Z}[x,y] / \langle x^2, xy, y^2 \rangle $$

This is the ring of all polynomials of the form $a + bx + cy$ with integer coefficients, subject to the relations $x^2 = xy = y^2 = 0$. So multiplication is

$$ (a + bx + cy)(d + ex + fy) = ad + (ae+bd) x + (af+cd)y $$

Every number of the form $bx + cy$ is a root of the polynomial $t^2$.

Of course, this example only needed one variable, not two, but I think it's more interesting with two.

Comment: Could you add some details regarding the notations you use ? I've never met them before.

Comment: $\mathbf{Z}[x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots]$ is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}$ and variables $x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots$. I'm computing a quotient of that ring by the ideal generated by all of the elements $x_0^2+1$, $x_1^2 + 1$, $x_2^2 + 1$, $\ldots$. This ring is sort of like I've added the complex unit $\mathbf{i}$, but then I kept going and added infinitely more, different complex units, all unrelated to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A = \prod_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the polynomial $f(x) = 2x$ over $A.$ It has infinitely many zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example: Every abelian group $R$ admits a unique commutative ring structure such that if $f\in R[x]$ is a polynomial whose constant term is zero, then every element in $R$ is a root of $f$.

Let $(R,+)$ be an abelian group with identity element $0$. Define multiplication $*$ on $R$ by
$$ a*b=0 \text{ for all }a,b\in R.$$
It is easy to verify that $(R,+,*)$ is a commutative ring. Every polynomial $f$ in $R[x]$ with a zero constant term has every element of $R$ as its root. So, to obtain a polynomial whose roots form a set of a given cardinality, it suffices to have an abelian group of that cardinality.

To prove the uniqueness of this structure, suppose $(R,+,*)$ is a commutative ring such that if $f\in R[x]$ is a polynomial whose constant term is zero, then every element in $R$ is a root of $f$.
Let $a,b$ be elements of $R$. Since $ax\in R[x]$ is a polynomial whose constant term is zero, $b$ is a root of $ax$, that is, $a*b=0$ .